# Usar ArrayList ou LinkedList

Tags: java, lista, lista-encadeada

A interface `List` tem varias implementações, entre elas `ArrayList` e `LinkedList`. Geralmente venho utilizando somente `ArrayList`, mas gostaria de saber em quais cenários é recomendado utilizar a implementação `LinkedList` em vez `ArrayList` e se há algum ganho nessa mudança.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link: https://www.devmedia.com.br/diferenca-entre-arraylist-vector-e-linkedlist-em-java/29162

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Em quais cenários é recomendado utilizar a implementação `LinkedList` em vez `ArrayList`

Se não puder justificar o uso de uma `LinkedList` use `ArrayList`. Ela deve ser o padrão por ser simples e rápida. Lista ligada não pode acessar um elemento qualquer com complexidade de tempo constante (O(1)), precisa ser, na média, meio linear (O(n/2)), o que pode ser de um pouco a extremamente mais lento, conforme o tamanho.

Quando precisa inserir ou remover itens no meio da lista, e em alguns casos mesmo no fim (quase sempre dá para resolver ou aceitar os casos ruins no fim), aí a lista ligada pode ser um pouco mais útil. Mas só é em alguns casos também, porque para inserir você precisa saber onde está e isto tem um custo semelhante à inserção/remoção em um `ArrayList`, então o ganho se perde em grande parte das operações, se não em todas.

Geralmente quando precisa de muita inserção/remoção uma árvore costuma ser melhor que uma lista, então ambas são escolhas ruins. Lista ligada hoje em dia é usado em bem poucos casos, onde realmente o acesso segue um padrão de lista ligada e não de outra estrutura.

> Há algum ganho nessa mudança?

Em várias operações o ganho é brutal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).